# Internet Explorer Hell With Background Images

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-image

I'd consider myself an advanced web developer but I'm pretty stumped as to what I'm doing to cause Internet Explorer to show my background image on a header tag in one place but not in another place with the exact same code.

I think my eyes have been looking at this site and code for too long to have anything pop out at me, so as a last resort, I'm reaching out here.

The staged site can be found here: http://honestagency.com/websites/hal10/

The problem is that in the box under the "Procedures" box on the home page, there should be a green banner showing across from the "Meet The Doctors" banner. The "Meet The Doctors" banner uses near identical CSS code.

```
.home_content div.left div.living_healthy h1.living_healthy_fold{background-image:url('../images/folds/living_healthy.png');position:absolute;left:-16px;top:20px;width:448px;height:76px;text-indent:-5000px;}    
.home_content div.right div.meet_doctors h1.meet_doctors_fold{background-image:url('../images/folds/meet_doctors.png');position:absolute;right:-16px;top:20px;width:394px;height:76px;text-indent:-5000px;}
```

The HTML respectively is:

```
<h1 class="living_healthy_fold">Living Healthy</h1>
<h1 class="meet_doctors_fold">Meet The Doctors</h1>
```

I its probably a really easy solution but I'm super stumped. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer are you using? I see the same result in IE8 and FF3.6

Comment: Oops, sorry, I'm testing in Firefox 4 and 5 and Internet Explorer 8. Firefox is running on a Mac and IE on Windows Vista on a Compaq laptop.

Comment: looks like IE7. There is an issue with the banner being position absolute and the parent being relative.

Comment: How would I manage to pull the banner outside of the holding div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a z-index on the .living_healthy_fold class.

```
.home_content div.left div.living_healthy h1.living_healthy_fold{
   background-image:url('../images/folds/living_healthy.png');
   position:absolute;
   left:-16px;
   top:20px;
   width:448px;
   height:76px;
   text-indent:-5000px;
   z-index:10;
}
```

Might not solve though as changing the dom in the developer tools seems to fix the issue so it's hard to find the right solution.

Comment: I knew the answer would be really simple! I actually had missed setting the width on the holder DIV! Setting that with the left/right padding subtracted off of it fixed the problem.

Moving too fast towards really tight dealines.

Thanks for the speedy help everyone!